# Docker compyling python file in Dockerfile

Tags: python, django, docker

I would to create a docker image from my django app but I don't want to pull my .py file.

For doing this I need a way to compile my python file in docker then remove all *.py and left only *.pyc file.

If I simply write `**/*.py` in the `.dokerignore` file, I get the error

> ImportError: bad magic number in 'ajaxfuncs': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

because my original *.py file was compiled with a different python version (local python3.6.0 docker python3.6 for alpine)

So as workaround I would build my python file in dockerfile and then remove all py

First in my .dockerignorefile i put: **/*.pyc

Then in my Dockerfile think to use python -m py_compile for generate my new *.pyc files:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
EXPOSE 8000
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache make linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN mkdir /Code
WORKDIR /Code
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /Code/

RUN python -m py_compile /Code/ajaxfuncs/ajax.py /Code/ajaxfuncs/asktempl.py /Code/ajaxfuncs/group.py /Code/ajaxfuncs/history.py /Code/ajaxfuncs/template_import.py

RUN rm -rf /Code/ajaxfuncs/*.py
ENTRYPOINT python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

but when I run my application seem that compiler does not compile my files, because no pyc was found.

If I remove the pyc entry in `.dockerignore` I again get the error:

> ImportError: bad magic number in 'ajaxfuncs': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Does someone know how I can compile python file during docker container creation or another method for avoid *.py file in container?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Ignoring all pyc files seems the right thing to do to avoid having magic numbers mismatch, what error do you get at compile time? It shouldn't complain about missing pyc, it shouldn't look for them at all

Comment: I don't know the answer to your magic number mismatch or missing files, but this will still leave a layer behind with the .py files, even though they're removed from the final image. You should do a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to get a clean image without a layer containing them.